# CSS skewed rectangle goes outside container

Tags: html, css

I have a red container I skewed of 35 degrees with its transform origin is set to the bottom left. The image below shows this highlighting the padding of its parent container that the red box must not go out.

[image: bla bla bla]

The skew effect works fine but not in responsive, where the top right angle overflows the perimeter of the container element. This is the current behavior or the red rectangle:

[image]

And this is the behavior I want to achieve for it. The skewed box must entirely  stay inside the perimeter delimited by the container padding, as this:

[image]

Ideas?

This snippet reproduces my case:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.red-box > div {
  padding: 0 10px;
  transform: skew(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-box">
    <div>PARKS AND GARDENS IN LONDON</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.vivilondra.it/images/vivilondra/images2/regents-park-top.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: You could use the CSS 3 calc function. to calculate how much the top edge is shifted over, and then subtract that from a width of 100%. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Are you skewing a pseudoelement?

Comment: I created a snippet reproducing the problem, take a look on that. @abluejelly no, the skew is done to a real element.

Comment: @neallred I search for some formulas to get the exact width of the inclined edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @neallred I've found a solution using trigonometry rules.

The red box should set its width to its 100% minus its height multiplicated by the tangent of the degrees used in the skew transformation. So:

`width: 100% - height * tan(35)`.

In my snippet I wanted to use fewer literals as possible so I forced the red box's text to stay in a single line and in this way I obtained the exact height of the box as `1em + vertical_padding` and rewriting the above formula as `100% - (1em + vertical_padding) * 0.700208`, forcing the `line-height: 1em` before.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.red-box {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - (1em + 20px) * 0.700208);
}
.red-box > div {
  padding: 0 10px;
  transform: skew(35deg);
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-box">
    <div>PARKS AND GARDENS IN LONDON</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.vivilondra.it/images/vivilondra/images2/regents-park-top.jpg" />
</div>
```

I hope could be help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS 3 calc function. to calculate how much the top edge is shifted over, and then subtract that from a width of 100%. See developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Did you figure out the measurements? It's a trigonometry problem. I think the taller side is sin(55degrees) * height of the original red box (or h). This would be 0.819 * h. The shorter side would be cos(55degrees) * h, or 0.574 * h. You only need to know about the shorter (bottom) side, because you need to shorten the new box by that much. If h_final = 0.574 * h, then it would be:

```
.red-box {
  .
  .
  .
  width: calc(100% - h_finalpx)
}
```

Comment: Your ideas is good. I used trigonometry to solve the problem, check my final answer.