# Skewed div outside its parent container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of divs that are breaking its parent container. I would like to know how to contain them.

Here's a copy of my pen: https://codepen.io/buzztnt/pen/oNgVOLO

```css
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-right: 2px green solid;
}

img {
  -webkit-transform: skew(35deg) scale(1.5);
  transform: skew(35deg) scale(1.5);
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-2 wrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313__340.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

I have also explored [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093706/css-skewed-rectangle-goes-outside-container) solution but I cannot use the "auto" value in the calc function as I want the images to be responsive.

Comment: overflow hidden need to go to an upper element, not the skewed container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  When you skew the div and img you have to think about what happens to the shape.

```css
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px green solid;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

img {
  -webkit-transform: skew(35deg) scale(1.5);
  transform: skew(35deg) scale(1.5);
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

div{border:black 1px solid;}

.container-fluid{
  overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-2 wrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313__340.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```